# Winforms - Import multiple text files into the same datatable

Tags: c#, winforms, text

I need to import multiple text files into the same `datatable`.  I am using an `openfiledialog` with multiselect set to true.  I got this working when selecting only one file, but the requirements are to select many text files.  How can I achieve this?  This is the function that creates the `datatable`:

```
        public static DataTable DataTableFromTextFile(string[] data)
    {
        DataTable result;


        result = FormDataTable(data);



        return result;
    }

    private static DataTable FormDataTable(string[] LineArray)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        AddColumnToTable(LineArray, ref dt);

        AddRowToTable(LineArray, ref dt);

        return dt;
    }

    private static void AddRowToTable(string[] valueCollection, ref DataTable dt)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < valueCollection.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] values = valueCollection[i].Split(new[] { "|" }, 5,  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            string[] col1 = values[0].Split(new[] { ":" }, 3, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            int count = values.Length;
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
    }

    private static void AddColumnToTable(string[] columnCollection, ref DataTable dt)
    {
        string[] columns = columnCollection[0].Split(new[] { "|" }, 5, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        string[] col1 = columns[0].Split(new[] { ":" }, 3, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        string[] names = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g" };
            for(int i = 0; i < columns.Count() + col1.Count(); i++)
            {
                DataColumn dc = new DataColumn(names[i], typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add(dc);
            }
    }
```

All of the text files have the same format.  I am loading data from one text file into an array, and then calling this function to create the `datatable` with the array in the constructor.  Can someone please show me how to accomplish the same thing with multiple text files.  Please let me know if you need more info.  I am somewhat new to this!

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you read the file in? What does `DataTableFromTextFile` do that couldn't be handled by `FormDataTable`? Do you really need to use `ref` here? (I don't think DataTables are passed by value by default). Also it would probably be better designed if you input a multi-dimensional array instead of a one dimensional you split later, cause that way you just assume the later split string does fit your format

Comment: Do what your are doing, except for each file. [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.multiselect?view=netframework-4.7#System_Windows_Forms_OpenFileDialog_Multiselect) has an example of how to access all selected files.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`FileNames`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filenames(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the FileDialog to get the list of all selected filenames.

I have created a new method called `DataTableFromAllTextFiles` to handle the array of filenames and to return a datable with all rows in it, similar to your `DataTableFromTextFile`:

```
// read the files and put the content in a Datatable
public static DataTable DataTableFromAllTextFiles(string[] files)
{
   DataTable result = null;

   foreach(var file in files) {
        //  read one file 
        var LineArray = File.ReadAllLines(file);
        // on the first one ...
        if (result == null) 
        {
            // ... create columns
            result = new DataTable();
            AddColumnToTable(LineArray, ref result);
        }
        // add the rows
        AddRowToTable(LineArray, ref result);
    }

   return result;
}
```

This is then called with the `FileNames` property of the filedialog:

```
  var ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
  ofd.Multiselect = true;
  ofd.ShowDialog();
  // FileNames holds an array of string with filenames (fullpath)
  var alldatarows = DataTableFromAllTextFiles(ofd.FileNames);
```